# freebsd: configure a different default directory

Tags: linux, unix, console, freebsd, home-directory

When I ssh into my freebsd I want to be automatically in another directory, and not my home directory.

I.e. instead of `/users/home/john` I want to be in `/users/home/john/what/i/am/working/on`

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -t jdoe@example.com 'cd /tmp && exec /bin/sh'
```

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest case of this is pretty easy.  In your ~jdoe/.profile you can add:

```
if [ X$SSH_TTY != X ]; then
   cd /users/home/john/what/i/am/working/on
fi
```

If you're looking for the system to *remember* which directory you're in, per-terminal, and go back to the right one when you log back in on that terminal, that's more complex but still do-able with shell.  Since $SSH_TTY is a filename, you can prepend "~/.mydirs/" to it, and use that filename to hold a copy of the CWD for the session of that terminal.  It's more complex than that, but this is the general idea.

Hope this helps!
-pbr

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh john@someplace:/path/to/wherever
```

notice the colon                     ^

Comment: with which version of ssh is that possible? i always get 'could not resolve hostname xyz:/path ... and i dont see anything close to your suggestion in 'man ssh'. did you mix that up with 'scp'?